# Why is ES6 working on Express.js generator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I'm just confused as to why I'm able to use things like arrow functions and the new ES6 syntax after using the Express.js generator to start a web application. I haven't done any additional setup; I just typed `express --view=hbs myapp` and, voila, I can suddenly use arrow functions in both the server side and browser side without any problem.

Is this just some hidden feature I wasn't aware of? I don't see any node modules baked in that would suggest how this is even working.

Comment: What version of node are you running?

Comment: Arrow functions [were available from v4 of Node](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/). Compatibility for ES6 in browsers varies.

Comment: While you can use arrow functions in node for quite some time, you can't reliably use them at the client side since some browsers still don't suport it (e.g. IE11 will unlikely ever support it).

Comment: How were you running your app before, and what problems did you have with using arrow functions then?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the Node.js version. Node.js is increasingly supporting most of the ES6 features by default. [node.green](http://node.green) has a mapping of ES6 features, and the versions they work on.

You'd need additional setup (Babel, etc.) only for the features which are not supported, like ES6 modules.